# Redirect page when direct address is entered in php

Tags: php, redirect, whmcs

I have a website with this domain: [paydarsamane.com](https://paydarsamane.com)
and i set up a client portal on a sub domain with written with php in this url: [portal.paydarsamane.com](https://portal.paydarsamane.com)

I want to make sure the portal doesn't open when a user write direct url in browser or opens it from an email link.
When that happened, redirect homepage or other page
But when user clicks on the portal login link (Located at main domain) Open correctly and show portal contents

Because I don't know php and don't know its infrastructure, I don't have any mentality about it.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution :**
you can read this articel to understand how to set cookie to another domain and then redirect to that page , so when user directly access the page the cookie is not saved in browser localstorage and then you can act properly :
[share-localstorage-sessionstorage-between-different-domains](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/share-localstorage-sessionstorage-between-different-domains-eb07581e9384)

**Second Solution :**
as you mentioned in comments you can use referral url too. like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// use referral host domain , not full url
   var referral_domain = "<?php echo $referral_domain; ?>";

// check if referral is set 
if(!localStorage.getItem('referral')){
    localStorage.setItem('referral', referral_domain);
}
if(localStorage.getItem('referral')){
    // you want to update 
    if(localStorage.getItem('referral') !== "example.url"){ 

        // redirect user back to where he came from fo example
        history.go(-1);
    }
}
else{

    // redirect user back to where he came from fo example
    history.go(-1);
}

</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, if user blocked cookies what happens?

Comment: Can't do it much easier with referral url? Check referral to see if the previous link to the page is ready for the user otherwise redirect to another site?

Comment: i meant to say localstorage , Cookies and local storage serve different purposes. Cookies are mainly for reading server-side, whereas local storage can only be read by the client-side. you can do stuff with javascript then.

Comment: yes you can use referral url , but when you do some works then referral link changes , you must do some check there too. there allway a lot of way to do a job done.

Comment: When will the referral link change? May not work for some users? Or is it public and can it be counted on?
Can you introduce a piece of code in this regard?

Comment: added example how to merge localstorage with referral url . hope it helps.